# Configure ssh on Ubuntu 16.04 recovery mode

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ufw

So I have a dedicated server. My host was able to get me to recovery mode. I am able to log in using ssh. Here's my dilemma. 
I accidentally changed ssh ports while logged in and forgot to add a rule to allow ufw incoming connections. Therefore I am locked out. 
Now, I am in recovery mode in Ubuntu through ssh. It uses a zsh shell it appears.

How do I make a rule in ufw from recovery mode to allow connections on that incoming port? If it is not possible, how do I disable ufw altogether and re enable it later?

Thanks.

Comment: 'service ssh start'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the value in **/etc/ufw/ufw.conf**

from **Enabled=yes** to **no**. Then do a restart

Comment: it doesn't work. It tells me this. zsh: no such file or directory: /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
root@sysresccd /root %

Comment: Are you actually booted into the Ubuntu system or running a livecd? It sure looks like you have booted a livecd image.  So you may need to actually mount your Ubuntu filesystems, and make the changes on the Ubuntu filesystems.

Comment: How do I mount? I'm connecting to a remote server.

Comment: Ok I seemed to have tried to mount it, but with this error:
mount: /dev/sda1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Comment: Try `fdisk -l` to find the correct partition first

Comment: Why are you trying to mount it using NTFS?

Comment: I managed to fix it. Here's what I did:
mount /dev/sd3 /mnt
Then I went to cd /mnt/etc/ufw

Then disabled it.

Comment: This worked for me! In recovery mode, my disk was mounted at `/mnt` already, so I went to `/mnt/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` and disabled ufw as suggested